# Conditional Formatting not working with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I'm using the below formula to input the name of my excel sheet into a cell. When i try to use conditional formatting on that cell and use the option "use a formula to determine which cells to format" to format the cell the data does not change.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

I'm trying to get my sheet name (which is a date written as 010117) to display as 01/01/17. Since excel wont allow me to use the "/" symbol in the sheet name conditional formatting appears to be my only option but it doesn't work in this instance.

Options?

Comment: Can you change the sheet name? I think the issue is that it's starting with a `0` and Excel doesn't seem to like that.  Is your end goal to have the sheet name in the cell, or is that perhaps a step to get you to an end goal?  It's a little ridiculous, *but* if you can rename your sheet to `10117`, this seems to work: `=TEXT(DATE("20"&RIGHT(0&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2),MID(0&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),3,2),LEFT(0&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2)),"mm/dd/yy")`

Comment: That's quote overkill alright. Its more for consistency because ill have 365 sheets in the one excel file so i just like to have the dates set like 010117,020117 etc on my sheet names.

Comment: Even by removing the 0 though conditional formatting still doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Is VBA a solution for you? Or does it need to be formula only?

Comment: VBA would suit, i just haven't got a clue where to start with it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UDF that you can use to get the sheet name, in the style you want.  Please note it does *not* check that it's a valid Date format, it simply throws the `/` in between every two numbers.  Put this in a Workbook module.

```
Function sheetNameToDate()
Application.Volatile
Dim shtNm As String
shtNm = ActiveSheet.Name
sheetNameToDate = Left(shtNm, 2) & "/" & Mid(shtNm, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(shtNm, 2)
End Function
```

So, in a sheet, in any cell, you can type `=sheetNameToDate()` and it'll return the sheet name in the format `01/01/17`, `02/01/17`, etc.  You can then do a Conditional Format that is, for example `=sheetNameToDate()="01/01/17"` and it'll return `TRUE` if that's so.

Comment: When i do that all it returns is "#NAME?"

Comment: @Exhausted - Hmm. Your sheet is only 6 numbers long, yes? No leading/trailing spaces? Can you please let me know what sheet name is getting a `#NAME` error? All of them? You *may* need to add `Worksheetfunction.` before each `Left()`, `Mid()` and `Right()`, but it ran in Excel 2010 without issue.